# Is there a Python function to solve index value error in random forest?

Tags: python, random-forest

On running the following code in Python:

```
rfcimp = pd.Series(rfc.feature_importances_,index = X.columns)
rfcimp.plot(kind = 'barh', figsize = (12,8))
```

I am facing the below error:

> ValueError: Length of passed values is 18, index implies 21

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `X.columns` has too many values

Comment: Please also add in your data so that we can check

Comment: I removed 3 columns from dataset X and it worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should filter `X` for the features you are training your RF with before passing it to `index`